# laravel return results when looking inside a pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have a gallery table and a tag table. A pivot table 'gallery_tag' exists with a many-to-many relationship.

I am struggling to think of a way where I can show the gallery (Gallery::) images with just of say 'red' (tag id: 2) on my page.

I understand how to do it if tag_id was stored in the gallery table but how do I search my Tag:: or Gallery:: for that particular ID?

I know this code would never work but hopefully it'll explain what I am trying to do:

```
$red        =   Gallery::wherePivot('id', '=', 2)->get();
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you access from Tag model `$red=Tag::where(['id'=>2])->with('gallery')->get()`

Comment: I get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::gallery(). What does that gallery reference? The table?

Comment: that is the relation of tags model. or is it galleries? show the relations code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gallery model**:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag','gallery_tag'); 
}
```

**Tag Model**:

```
public function galleries()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Gallery','gallery_tag'); 
}
```

then, this will give the all the images of galleries with tag id 2.

```
$tag=Tag::where(['id'=>2])->with('galleries')->first();
foreach($tag->galleries as $gallery)
{
     print_r($gallery->image);  //image is the column in galleries table
}
```

See  [Eloquent Many to Many Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) in docs.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense!

Comment: @Paolo I'm glad this helped.